# Make a Graph Webpage

Tags: css, graph, html

I want to make the whole webpage into a graph, like a blueprint (the colour scheming). And then i want to plot a graph in the same page. So should i use some code to make the grid or should i just make an image file and make it the background.
The grid should be preferably something like this : [Graph](http://www.math-drills.com/graphpaper/images/graph_paper_threeline_metric_200_100_025_001_pin.jpg), or with the proper coloring [Blueprint Graph](http://cdn2.stormgrounds.com/stormgrounds-cdn/media/blue-print-graph.jpg)

If code is suggested, please give an overview of how to do so.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something you could do with HTML5 Canvas, although maybe that's above and beyond what you're looking for. [Here's a pretty good free course](https://www.udacity.com/course/html5-canvas--ud292) that has relevant examples.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're going to be plotting points on the graph, your best bet is to create an element, such as a `<div>`, and give it a fixed width and height.  Then apply a background image of the graph paper to that element.  You'll need to use absolute positioning when plotting points, so it's key that the graph stays in place and doesn't get skewed based on differing viewports.

If you wanted the entire viewport to be a graph, you'll need to reference the upper-left corner when plotting points (start at 0,0) since users' browsers will have varying widths and heights.